# How does ReflectionFunction's isDeprecated work?

Tags: php, reflection

I'm trying to use the following function to loop through loaded files and find depreciated functions.

```
//loads all files
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/loader.php'; 

$functions = get_defined_functions();

foreach ($functions['user'] as $func) {

    $rf = new ReflectionFunction('$func');
    var_dump($rf->isDeprecated());
}
```

Some functions have markup like the following, yet it's still return `false`. In fact every single function returns `false` yet there are a lot with markup stating `@deprecated`.

```
 **
 *
 * @since 0.71
 * @deprecated 1.5.1
 * @deprecated Use get_post()
 *
 * @param int $postid
 * @return array
 */
```

ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReflectionFunction::isDeprecated` does not check documentation comments; it only checks an internal flag that can be set by PHP extensions on the functions they expose.

For example, [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/ereg/ereg.c#53) is the part of the source for the [`ereg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.regex.php) extension where its functions are declared and marked as deprecated (the `DEP` part in `PHP_DEP_FE` stands for "deprecated").

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for Reflection, it applies only to built-in functions that have the ZEND_ACC_DEPRECATED flag set, so it's not applicable to userland methods or functions